# tree test for Robinson arithmetic axioms

Tags: logic

My task was to use trees to show that the sentences (a-d) follow from the Robinson arithmetic axioms.  Can someone tell me if any of these are right / complete.  Some just felt too easy.
a. 0 ≠ s0
b. 0 ≠ ss0
c. s0 ≠ ss0
d. s0 ≠ sss0

where s is the successor function
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First: All of the sentences stated in a-d (well, I am looking at the sentence right next to the a-d respectively) are *false* in standard arithmetic, so you can't mean to say that you have to show them to follow form the axioms for standard arithmetic. Rather, I assume you mean to say that you show that their negations are all true, since without the negation, they all lead to contradictions (i.e. all closed branches in the tree test)

Second: it would be good to know exactly what axioms you are working with. The [Wikipedia page on Robinson Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic) lists the relevant axioms as:

$Q1: \forall x \ sx \neq 0$

$Q2: \forall x \forall y (sx = sy \to x = y)$

Now, I find it weird that you do not have those axioms in the root of your tree. In fact, you don't seem to use any universal eliminations at all ...  are you working with a different set of axioms?  Or were you told to use the tree in some special way?

Third: for a) you write down $0 \neq s0$ ... but using the above axiom you can at best get $s0 \neq 0$. Similar comments apply to all of your proofs, where you seem to have the left and right sides switched. But maybe in your axiom it is switched from what the Wikipedia page says? Again, what axioms exactly are you working with?

Likewise, your instantiation of $Q2$ is the contrapositive of what you end up with if you use the axiom from the Wikipedia page. Is that how your axiom is defined? Again, please add your axioms to your post.

OK, I'll evaluate your specific trees now with the assumotion that your axioms actually look like:

$Q1: \forall x \ 0 \neq sx$

$Q2: \forall x \forall y (x \neq y \to sx \neq sy)$

If so:

Your a) is correct.

b) is also correct, though the second line is unnecessary

c) ... depending on how exactly your tree rules are defined, you may have to get $\neg \neg 0 = s(0)$ in the left branch .... Otherwise correct

d) same comment as for c)

In all: They definitely all have the right idea and have correct proof plan, so good job! It's just a matter that all the exact formal i's are dotted and t's are crossed ... but without knowing the exact formalizations of your axioms and rules, I can't comment any further on that.

Comment: sorry i meant to add the axioms.  as you can see they are a bit different than what's listed on wikipedia.

Comment: @mayalarson Thanks!  OK, so that's exactly what I thought they had to be looking at your statements.  OK, so you used all those correctly too then. My only remaining concern is when you branch on the conditional. Typically, the tree rule says that in that case you need to write down the negation of whatever antecedent you have, and since your anteceddent is already a negation, you end up with a double negation ... and you'll need to use a separate rule to get rid of that double negation. But again, your tree rules might be slightly different.